# How to save inputbox value in array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom-events

I'm new to Javascript.
I want to store input boxes value in array, but I have problem with this.
I use below code; please guide me:

```
<form>
 <input type="text" id="NumElement" />
 <button onclick="return Give()" />Give</button>
 <div id="inputs"></div>
 <p>Block Number: <input type="text" id="NoArrey" /></p>
 <button onclick="return Show()" />Show</button>
 <input type="text" id="Result" />
</form>
<script>

  function Give() {
       var Num = document.getElementById('NumElement').value;
       var i = 0;
       for (i = 0; i < Num; i++) {
         var m = i + 1;
         inputs.innerHTML = inputs.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' id='v" + m + "'>";
       };
       inputs.innerHTML = inputs.innerHTML +"<br><button id='Save' onclick='return Save()'>Save</button>";

       return false;
  }

  function Save() {
       var MyArray = new Array();
       var j = 0;
       for (j = 0; j < Num; j++) {
             var InputValue  = document.getElementById('v' + j);
             MyArray.push(InputValue.value);
       }

  function Show() {
       var no = document.getElementById('NoArrey').value;
       document.getElementById("Result").value = (MyArray[no]);
       return false;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did a typo but in the save() function you don't declare var num. You are declaring num in the give() function.

this should work.

**EDIT:**

```
function Give() {
       var Num = document.getElementById('NumElement').value;
       var i = 0;
       for (i = 0; i < Num; i++) {
         var m = i + 1;
         inputs.innerHTML = inputs.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' id='v" + m + "'>";
       };
       inputs.innerHTML = inputs.innerHTML +"<br><button id='Save' onclick='return Save()'>Save</button>";

       return false;
  }

  function Save() {
       var Num = document.getElementById('NumElement').value;
       var MyArray = new Array();
       var j = 0;
       for (j = 0; j < Num; j++) {
             var InputValue  = document.getElementById('v' + j);
             MyArray.push(InputValue.value);
       }

  function Show() {
       var no = document.getElementById('NoArrey').value;
       document.getElementById("Result").value = (MyArray[no]);
       return false;
  }
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and show all the <script> tag or it's too long ? Plus can you record error on console ?